# What is the reason to put a dollar sign in front of interpolation in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am going through the tutorial and find the code below. I understand that putting the dollar sign as a suffix means it's observable. But what's the reason to put a dollar sign in front of `` this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`) `` like that?

```
/** PUT: update the hero on the server */
updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
  );
}
```

Comment: Well what happens if you remove the dollar sign? Have you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals? This isn't specific to Angular or TypeScript, but is also covered in e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Template literals or  Template strings. It is feature of JavaScript and  not specific to angular. To learn more visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Using template string you can use variable inside the string. For using this `` (backticks) is used instead of quotes('' or "").
For exmaple:

```js
const str = 'Hello';
const str2 = `${str} world`; 
//Output will be Hello World
console.log(str2);
```

If you use the traditional approach 
then would need concatenation. `str2 = str + ' World';`

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript string interpolation. It allows you to interpolate expressions into string literals.

```js
const myVar = 'World!';

const string1 = 'Hello, ' + myVar;
const string2 = `Hello, ${myVar}`;

console.log(string1, string2);
```

The dollar sign for observable properties is just a convention, it is not syntactical.